# Get the last X rows that meet the conditions of a criteria Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am having difficulty with a formula in google spreadsheet.

This is what I require:

The search criteria it is found in cell "D18" of the sheet "Visor BD Fichas".

In the sheet "BD Historial de visitas" you must go through the column "B8:B" where you must find all the matches of the search criteria that we have in cell "D18" of the sheet "Visor BD Fichas". This criterion is repeated many times throughout the column.

From there, I want to get the data from column "C8:C" which corresponds to each row that matches the search criteria in column "B8:B".

I easily achieve this with the following formula:

`=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK($D$18)=FALSE;INDEX(FILTER('BD Historial de visitas'!$C$8:$C;'BD Historial de visitas'!$B$8:$B=$D$18);1);"");"No hay datos disponibles")`

And changing the number "1" by the row number from which a value will be returned.
For example, if I put "2", I get the second match. If I put "3", I get the third match. And so on.

So far so good, it returns the values ​​correctly.
The problem is that I don't want to get the rows from top to bottom, I want to get from bottom to top. That is, I want to get the last added rows that match the search criteria "D18".

To do this, I format my previous formula a bit and get the following:

`=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK($D$18)=FALSE;INDEX(FILTER('BD Historial de visitas'!$C$8:$C;'BD Historial de visitas'!$B$8:$B=$D$18);COUNTA(FILTER('BD Historial de visitas'!$C$8:$C;'BD Historial de visitas'!$B$8:$B=$D$18);)-0);"");"No hay datos disponibles")`

Now here the number "-0" corresponds to the last row. If I change this to "-1" I get the penultimate row. If I change it to "-2" I get the ante penultimate row. And so on until I reach the 15 rows that I require.

So far everything is correct. But this is where I have the big problem.

If you look at the attached image, you can see that the only 3 matches that have been found have been returned to me, starting from the last row. However, below the last match, the formula returns the error "#REF!" "The result matrix has not been extended because the data in C43 would be overwritten."

[image: error #REF!]

It should be mentioned that there is the same formula (altering the desired row number) from row 39 to row 52.
Also, this error occurs in any row, whether it returns 3 rows with matching or 7.

After 2 days trying to find a solution to the problem and looking for similar solutions on google and stackoverflow, I still can't find the problem ...

Would someone be so kind as to give me some help with the formula?

Thank you very much in advance and sorry for the long text.

Answer (score 2):

to return last 6 values try:

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(D18)=FALSE;
 ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT(FILTER(
 {'BD Historial de visitas'!C8:C\ ROW('BD Historial de visitas'!C8:C)}; 
  'BD Historial de visitas'!B8:B=D18); 2; 0); 6; 1); ); "No hay datos disponibles")
```

---

### update:

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(D18)=FALSE;
 ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT(FILTER(
 {'BD Historial de visitas'!C8:F\ ROW('BD Historial de visitas'!C8:C)}; 
  'BD Historial de visitas'!B8:B=D18); 5; 0); 6; 4); ); "No hay datos disponibles")
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. One question, how should I get the data from several columns at the same time? I have tried modifying its formula by changing the 1 by 4 to get the data from 4 columns as well as modifying the range to ``` BD Historial de visitas'!$C$8:$F\ ROW('BD Historial de visitas'!$C$8:$F ```  but it didn't work ... You can help me? @player0

Comment: As I said in the previous comment, it is correct. Changing the value of 1 to the number of columns to be obtained (in this case 4) and changing the range of the table, the 4 columns are obtained. At first it didn't work for me because I use multiple cells horizontally merged. However, for unmerged cells, it works fine. Is there a way to get all 4 columns for cell combination? @player0

Comment: @Nerea see the update for last 6 values across 4 columns

Comment: Thank you very much for updating, however there is a problem with both formulas .... In case the new criterion does not have data to import or has fewer records than the criterion seen before, then the data of the previous criterion is still displayed. Attachment screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17rpwB80tCG9KD8PDXs4klN3pMQQp8o_W/view?usp=sharing      @player0

Comment: @Nerea can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: In order to see the record of any pet in the "Visor BD Fichas", you must go to the "BD Fichas" sheet, select the cell with a name from column B and click on the blue button "Ver producto" (it is a macro ). It will automatically load the data of this animal in the "Visor BD Fichas", and through it the cell "D18" will be filled with the name of the pet and your formula will bring the data of the other sheets.
Here the copy: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pxGWXJ6J8_4IHDLTwYef0DDepM-Ihtqz9K7pitjglhA/edit?usp=sharing @player0

Comment: When you switch from Imsa to Rita for example, you may see the problem that I mentioned in one of the comments above.  @player0